# Fail to install netopeer2 (22.04)

Tags: software-installation

I tried to install netopeer2 in Ubuntu 22.04.
But I got follow error;

---

```
$ sudo apt install netopeer2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  sysrepo
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  netopeer2 sysrepo
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 235 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,009 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
Get:1 http://kr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 sysrepo amd64 2.0.53-6build1 [23.1 kB]
Get:2 http://kr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 netopeer2 amd64 2.0.35-1ubuntu1 [212 kB]
Fetched 235 kB in 2s (98.4 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package sysrepo.
(Reading database ... 359520 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../sysrepo_2.0.53-6build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking sysrepo (2.0.53-6build1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package netopeer2.
Preparing to unpack .../netopeer2_2.0.35-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking netopeer2 (2.0.35-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up sysrepo (2.0.53-6build1) ...
Setting up netopeer2 (2.0.35-1ubuntu1) ...
/usr/share/netopeer2/merge_hostkey.sh: line 29: /dev/null: restricted: cannot redirect output
dpkg: error processing package netopeer2 (--configure):
 installed netopeer2 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 netopeer2
needrestart is being skipped since dpkg has failed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

---

What shall I do to install netopeer2?

T.I.A.

Comment: This appears to be a problem with the package itself - specifically, that the `postinst` script executes `/usr/share/netopeer2/merge_hostkey.sh` (and others) with `bash -r` (restricted shell mode) - I have no idea why...